# Chef recipe to clone several git repos to separate folders

Tags: chef-infra

I need to clone several git repositories into separate folders (i.e `/var/www/repo_name`).
It seems to me, I can do that with:

```rb
git node['git_folder'] do 
  repository node['git_repository']
  reference "master"
  action :sync
  user "username"
end
```

But how can I give several attributes to one recipe in the role?. Can I somehow use data bags for my needs? Is there any different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you would accomplish it using data bags:

Assuming you have the following data bag structure:

```
data_bags
  git_repos
    repo_1.json
    repo_2.json
```

Assuming you have the following data bag item structure:

```
{
  "id": "repo_1",
  "destination": "/var/www/repo_1",
  "url": "https://repo.to/clone.git,
  "revision": "master",
  "user": "username",
  "action": "sync"
}
```

The attributes `id`, `destination`, and `url` are required. If `revision`, `user`, or `action` are omitted, default values will be used in the recipe:

```rb
data_bag('git_repos').each do |name|
  repo = data_bag_item('git_repos', name)

  git repo['destination'] do 
    repository repo['url']
    reference  repo['revision'] || 'master'
    user       repo['user'] || 'username'
    action     repo['action'] ? repo['action'].to_sym : :sync
  end
end
```

As you can see, you *could* use data bags in this instance, but it's unclear to me why you would want to do so. In my opinion, this approach is far less intutive and much more difficult to reason about during debugging.

Comment: And another little question.. If i need to group databag items by project name, and than give a single attribute to the recipe, like node ['git-clone']['project'], how can i put it into recipe?.. Thx in advance.

Comment: @Blasterdick please ask another question on a different post.

Answer (score 0):

A recipe contains resource declarations, so just declare multiple resources:

```
git "/var/www/repo1" do
  repository https://github.com/myname/repo1.git
  action :checkout
end

git "/var/www/repo2" do
  repository https://github.com/myname/repo2.git
  action :checkout
end

git "/var/www/repo3" do
  repository https://github.com/myname/repo3.git
  action :checkout
end
```

Some people favour a loop in ruby, I'm reluctant unless the cookbook is being driven (from a databag?). I like clear statements of intent in my chef recipes.

Comment: Thx for your reply. This recipe will be used in a bunch of servers, and in every server there will be different attributes.. It seems to me, it would be better to do this like in users::sysadmins recipe do.

Comment: I've already did a recipe like yours', but I'm just curious, if i could use databags here..

Comment: @Blasterdick Looks like Seth has provided a data bag example.